# I cant type the letter "&" In Python (PyCharm) It replaces it with a space {BUG}

Tags: python, string, url, pycharm, character

Inside the " " of the variable char I have typed Shift7 and I got the space that u can see!
[image: Inside the " " I have typed the Shift7 and gives me a space]So I am trying to call an api with get request. And I want to pass as a parameter after: `<endpoint>&per_page=100`

But the character **'&'** when I type it, it gives me a **"space"**

Like:

`<endpoint> per_page=100`

> Even when I try to copy paste a url with a "&" character in the String it replaces it
> with a space and the api gives me error status.

**It seems that I cant use the character "&" anywhere as a character or as a String**

Any Ideas of what is going on?

Comment: Are you sure that the *char* it isn't followed by ***nbsp;*** (in the clipboard)? Also what happens if you manually type it? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: can you give us a full row of the code where this is happening ?
`<endpoint>&per_page=100` is not a correct syntax

Comment: I would try to change font, just to check.

Comment: What if you type it in another editor and reload it from PyCharm ?

Comment: @reportgunner the full code seems that is not the problem here. I just cant type & anywhere As a character or a string

Comment: @JacquesGaudin I will try that

Comment: @Jona let me check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jacques Gaudin Changing the Font worked. Thanx!

Comment: Great, could you tell us what font was causing the issue for future reference?

Comment: Font: Source Code Pro, Replaces every "&" with a "space" in PyCharm